# Переадресация на локальный сервер Polylang

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin, polylang

Сделал сайт на wordpress, локально. Установил плагин для мультиязычности polylang. Залил весь сайт на хостинг, вместе с бд - разумеется. И все работает хорошо, все страницы отображаются корректно. Но при смене языка, перекидывает на локальный сервер. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Читай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562 и переделывай.

Comment: Прочитал, но дубликатор у меня не работает. А в остальном, раньше все прекрасно переносилось в ручную, проблема возникла, только сейчас @SeVlad